# Print Magento Invoice Data To TCPDF File

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf, zend-framework

I have followed the instruction in the link ->
[TCPDF With Magento](http://www.ashrafulabedein.com/use-tcpdf-magento/), now I want to call the TCPDF library from `Invoice.php` file at `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php` because I want to print the invoice data to a TCPDF invoice.

How to use the functions to get the invoice data and print it to a TCPDF file?

Here are the functions which prints invoice data to a PDF file generated by Zend framework.

```
<?php

class Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Draw header for item table
     *
     * @param Zend_Pdf_Page $page
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _drawHeader(Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
    {
        /* Add table head */
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y -15);
        $this->y -= 10;
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0, 0, 0));

        //columns headers
        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Products'),
            'feed' => 35
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('SKU'),
            'feed'  => 290,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Qty'),
            'feed'  => 435,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Price'),
            'feed'  => 360,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tax'),
            'feed'  => 495,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Subtotal'),
            'feed'  => 565,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lineBlock = array(
            'lines'  => $lines,
            'height' => 5
        );

        $this->drawLineBlocks($page, array($lineBlock), array('table_header' => true));
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->y -= 20;
    }

    /**
     * Return PDF document
     *
     * @param  array $invoices
     * @return Zend_Pdf
     */
    public function getPdf($invoices = array())
    {
        $this->_beforeGetPdf();
        $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

        $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
        $this->_setPdf($pdf);
        $style = new Zend_Pdf_Style();
        $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                Mage::app()->getLocale()->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
            }
            $page  = $this->newPage();
            $order = $invoice->getOrder();
            /* Add image */
            $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());
            /* Add address */
            $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());
            /* Add head */
            $this->insertOrder(
                $page,
                $order,
                Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID, $order->getStoreId())
            );
            /* Add document text and number */
            $this->insertDocumentNumber(
                $page,
                Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId()
            );
            /* Add table */
            $this->_drawHeader($page);
            /* Add body */
            foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item){
                if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                /* Draw item */
                $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
                $page = end($pdf->pages);
            }
            /* Add totals */
            $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                Mage::app()->getLocale()->revert();
            }
        }
        $this->_afterGetPdf();
        return $pdf;
    }

    /**
     * Create new page and assign to PDF object
     *
     * @param  array $settings
     * @return Zend_Pdf_Page
     */
    public function newPage(array $settings = array())
    {
        /* Add new table head */
        $page = $this->_getPdf()->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
        $this->_getPdf()->pages[] = $page;
        $this->y = 800;
        if (!empty($settings['table_header'])) {
            $this->_drawHeader($page);
        }
        return $page;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to completely avoid `Zend_Pdf` from the playground, you need to rewrite `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice::getPdf()` method. Your custom `getPdf()` should somewhat look like this:

```
<?php
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice
{
    public function getPdf($invoices = array())
    {
        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {

            //get invoice order
            $order = $invoice->getOrder();

            //set registry current order as invoice order.
            $currentOrder = Mage::registry('current_order');
            if (!$currentOrder) {
                Mage::register('current_order', $order);
            }
            if ($currentOrder->getId() != $order->getId()) {
                Mage::unregister('current_order');
                Mage::register('current_order', $order);
            }

            //your tcpdf stuffs comes here
            $tcpdf = new TCPDF_TCPDF();

            //using magneto's default invoice print html file for preparing invoice content
            $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
            $html = $request->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('sales/order_print_invoice', 'sales.order.pdf.invoice')
                ->setTemplate('sales/order/print/invoice.phtml')
                ->toHtml();

            $tcpdf->AddPage();

            $tcpdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

            $tcpdf->lastPage();

            return $tcpdf->Output('sales_order_invoice_'.time().'.pdf', 'I');
        }


    }
}
```

I don't have previous experience with `tcpdf`. But from the above code, you will get the idea. `getPdf()` is the function which is responsible for using `zend_pdf` library to generate invoice pdf. By rewriting this method, you can use `tcpdf` in order to generate invoice pdf.

Here what we are doing is, using Magento's default invoice print phtml file to generate invoice pdf content. This invoice phtml file uses the class `Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Print_Invoice` class instance and it requires `Mage::registry('current_order')` to be set in order to render it.

Hope you can you use this as a starting point.

Comment: how to use this in magento2.